# Chrome-extension: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My goal is to send a simple message **from background.js to content-script** (test.js). I followed the example in here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple, but getting this error in background.js console log:

```
11111
33333 undefined
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

How to reproduce:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "myName",
  "description": "myDescription",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
   },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "notifications", "tabs"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('22222', request, sender);
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  }
);
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    console.log('11111');
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "playSound"}, function(resp) {
        console.log('33333', resp);
    }); 
});
```

My environment:

```
Chrome Version 96.0.4664.93 (Official Build) (x86_64)
chrome://extensions - all other extensions are turned off
OS: Mac Monterey 12.0.1
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.sendMessage sends to a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that runs in the tab but you didn't declare it.  You declared a popup, not a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are right. I thought the test.js counts as a content script. Didn't know it was under a different "category". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is for sending message from background script to content script

If someone using message sending code directly from doc (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple) and still getting the error make sure you reload the web page after changing code locally and add return true when receving the message.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(message);
  return true;
});
```